# How to include Jupyter notebook on Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook is a great tool and I would like to incorporate fully working note with Django shell on Django view. Is it possible without iframe?

Project owner wants to have seperate views with Jupyter notebook in user panel